# Rails 3 #update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails 4 app that was previously upgraded from Rails 3. I haven't worked much Rails 3 before. I came across this something like this `user.update_attributes({ attr => bulk_update_params[attr] }, :as => :admin)`. Rails 4 currently complains that `update_attributes` only accepts 1 argument and not 2.

I tried merging the `as: :admin` by doing `user.update_attributes({ attr => bulk_update_params[attr] }).merge(as: :admin)` but then i get greeted with something like "as" is not a known attribute".

Not entirely sure but how do I deal with the `as: admin` part? Is it safe to remove it entirely or there's a way to pass `as: :admin` to the original `user.update_attributes({ attr => bulk_update_params[attr] }, :as => :admin)` in Rails 4?

I think it has something to do with `attr_accessible` and `strong_params` just not sure how to work with it in Rails 4 now. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please give us the attributes a User have, and what is `as: :admin` in your context ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at strong parameters. The permitted attributes should be determined in the controller not the model

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

For example the controller would have

```
def customer_params
   if current_user.admin?
     params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname, :status)
   else
     params.require(:customer).permit(:fname, :lname)
   end
end

def update
  @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: I know about strong params. i'm asking about what to do with the `as` key. does it become, as in your example `customer_params = params.require(:customer).permit(:as, :blah, :blah)`?? where i'll be permiting the "as" key? doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: is `as` is attr_accessor?

Comment: if yes, then try `if current_user.as == 'admin'`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the as: admin into the hash

`user.update_attributes({ attr => bulk_update_params[attr], :as => :admin })`

You might also want to consider using update_attributes! (with a ! at the end) so if there are errors, it will blow up and not fail silently.